# What is the difference of "It is September" and "It is in September"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> It is September.
>
> It is **in** September.

There seems a difference, but I don't know it.

When to use the one over the other?

Comment: Could you tell us what you're trying to say?

Comment: @userr2684291 Sorry, it is from Duolingo French course but French clearly tells them apart, and the course creators explain it relating to these English. But I don't understand the difference, so came here to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, the following is how you would interpret the two sentences.

> It is September.

This means that the current month is September.

> It is **in** September.

Purely on its own, this sentence is awkward and unidiomatic. If we mean to say that the current month is September, we never say it is *in* September.

However, the sentence makes sense if the pronoun is referring to some kind of event:

> "When is the wedding?"
>   "It is (scheduled to be) **in** September."

---

Note that there are some alternatives to a standalone sentence about it being September—one even uses **in** and doesn't refer to an event:

> It is **now** September.
>   We **find ourselves** ***in*** September.